# How long the prototypal inheritance can practically be?

Tags: javascript

When you want to access the super.super.super class method, there must be some pointer->to pointer->to pointer dereference somewhere internally in the JavaScript engine, that could take a long time to dereference, right?

How long the prototypal inheritance chain can practically be, does it incur performance penalty to inherit a very long chain? 10? 100? 1000 levels?

Comment: I'd say if you have more than 3 levels, something is probably wrong with how you're modelling things.

Comment: Barring any optimizations (which browsers do and which is not covered in the specification), naive performance can be "expected" O(n), hiding among all the other work. For such a performance question (which will differ with implementations and usage), create some performance tests (that are actually relevant to the usage) and execute them in different environments.